# decompress zip string in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, zlib

I am trying to decompress a byte64 encoded string in Python 2.7.

I can verify that my string is valid by running this in the command line:

```
echo -n "MY_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING" | base64 -d | zcat
```

However, if I run this in Python2.7:

```
b64_data = 'MY_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING'
text_data = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(b64_data))
```

I get an exception:

> Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

Should I pass extra parameters to zlib.decompress to make it work?

Comment: zcat works with gzip format (gzip header + zlib data) while your python code processes zlib data only.

Comment: Yup, works with `gzip.decompress()` instead of zlib.

Comment: @RyanP gzip.decompress() is not available in Python 2.7

Comment: Ok, then. Works with `gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(b64_data))).read()`

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the comments, your data is in gzip format and not just zlib compressed data. In Python 2.7, you can use `GzipFile` with `StringIO` to process the string:

```
>>> from gzip import GzipFile
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> from base64 import b64decode
>>> data = 'H4sIAEm2algAAytJLS7hAgDGNbk7BQAAAA=='
>>> GzipFile(fileobj=StringIO(b64decode(data))).read()
'test\n'
```